# Values change using glcmTexture() with different zoom levels

Tags: google-earth-engine, texture

How can I use glcmTexture() in Google Earth Engine, without the output values change with different zoom levels?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. There are a couple of algorithms like this in EE. While you in principle can `reproject()` the resulting image to a fixed scale, that's usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, do you know a good library in python to get the texture metrics?

Comment: Nope, sorry....

Comment: It's not python, but if you just need a free open-source option I have an R package to calculate GLCM texture measures on spatial raster data (https://github.com/ailich/GLCMTextures).